# Chrome Devtools Remote IOS Debugging Network Domain Not Found

Tags: ios, debugging, networking, dns, devtools

I am trying to setup remote debugging between a Win 7 laptop running chrome and an Apple iPhone running Safari. I am using chrome-devtools to establish the connection.  I am using an ios-webkit-debug-server on the laptop and a python3 local http.server on the iPhone.  I can get the laptop to connect and identify the iphone as a remote device.  I copy and paste the link to devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/1.  I get the following messages. I have tried disablining the firewall but no change.  It appears that devtools cannot setup the network logging because it cannot find the network domain.Any help would be appreciated.

**iPhone**

- IOS V12.5.1
- Turned Web Inspector On
- Start Server with Python3 -m http.server
- In Safari (V12.5.1) I navigate to http://localhost:8000/test.html

**Laptop**

- OS is Win 7
- I start Powershell 7.1.3 running as administrator (WMF 5.1)
- I start "ios-webkit-debug-server -f chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html"
- I get Listing devices on :9221
- I get Connected :9222 to jim's iPhone (??????...)
- On Chrome I navigate to localhost:9221
- I get "iOS Devices: 1. localhost:9222 - jim’s iPhone"
- I click localhost:9222
- I get "Inspectable pages for jim’s iPhone: 1. http://localhost:8000/test.html
- I copy and paste "devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/1"
- I get following messages (Truncated error messages different commands network domain not found)

-07:27:59:432 Main._createAppUI: 39.85693359375 ms

-07:27:59.472 main.js:1 Main._showAppUI: 44.3681640625 ms

-07:27:59.616 main.js:1 Main._initializeTarget: 34.602783203125 ms

-07:27:59.718 main.js:1 Main._lateInitialization: 0.56689453125 ms

-07:28:00.424 protocol_client.js:1 Request Network.enable failed. {"code":-32601, "message":"
'Network' domain was not found","data":[{"code":-32601,"message":"'Network'domain was not found"}]}